# Make first Radio button checked in Loop using name attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have list of Radio buttons in loop like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="courses" id="course_1" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="courses" id="course_2" value="2">
<input type="radio" name="courses" id="course_3" value="3">
<input type="radio" name="courses" id="course_4" value="4">
```

I want to make first radio checked using **name** attribute **not id**.

Here is my Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/8AcYg/1/

Answer (score 6):

Use [.first()](http://api.jquery.com/first/)

```
$('input[name="courses"]').first().prop('checked', true)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/NsY3g/)

You can also use [:first](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/), [:eq(0)](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) or [.eq(0)](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) to do the same

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input[name='courses']:eq(0) ").attr("checked","checked");
```

or

```
$('input[name="courses"]:eq(0)').prop('checked', true);
```

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8AcYg/2/)**

reference **[attribute-equals-selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)** , **[attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)** , **[prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with native document method `getElementsByName` or `querySelector`

```
document.getElementsByName('courses')[0].checked = true;
```

or

```
document.querySelector('[name=courses]:first-child').checked = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this by setting first child's attribute to true

```
$('input:radio[name=courses]:first-child').attr('checked',true);
```

See in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sach1177/BuSag/1/)